# How can I set a keyword in URL & want to read that in Cakephp controller & then set it for view

Tags: php, cakephp, view, url-parameters

Hi I want to set a keyword value in a URL link which I have to send in mail, So on clicking on that link user will come on my website where I want to read that keyword value  by this `$this->params['url']` after getting this value, I have to set it for my view page where all results will come according to keyword value.
I have different keywords for different email ,so according to receiver mail when he/she will click on it he/she should get the results according to his/her keyword on his/her view.    All coding is done in cakephp

Answer (score 0):

If your action is as-

```
public function identify_user($userId = null){

}
```

then any url comes as www.example.com/users/identify_user/4 will take `$userId` as 4;

now, if

```
public function identify_user($userId = null, $identificationId = null){

}
```

then any url comes as `www.example.com/users/identify_user/4/abcdef12345` will take `$userId` as 4 and `$identificationId` as abcdef12345;

There is also other approach like named parameter or query parameter. Named parameter found as name => $value; (note: try to avoid named parameter, it will depreciated)

You can build url with query parameter and then ready query parameter with `$this->request->query();`

## now how to build url?

If you use first approach mean pass parameter then bulid link as-

```
$link = $this->Html->link('Link name to display', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'identify_user', $user['User']['id']));
```

here `$user['User']['id']` is coming from database;

**Named parameter:**

```
$link = $this->Html->link('Link name to display', array(
                                                    'controller' => 'Users',
                                                    'action' => 'identify_user',
                                                    'user_name' => $user['User']['name'],
                                                    'unique_id' => String::uuid()
                                                )
                                        );
```

read named parameter-

```
$this->request->params['named']['unique_id'];
```

**Query parameter-**

```
$link = $this->Html->link('Link name to display', array(
                                                    'controller' => 'Users',
                                                    'action' => 'identify_user',
                                                    '?' => array(
                                                        'user_name' => $user['User']['name'],
                                                        'unique_id' => String::uuid()
                                                    )
                                                )
                                        );
```

read query parameter-
$this->request->query('unique_id');